# Filtering a time series of returns by deleting some points

Tags: time-series, returns

I have a time series of returns of an asset (call this $ X_t $) which I have verified to be stationary. Let's say I generate a new time series $Y_i$ which is a filtered version of $X_t$ (that is I remove some points from $X_t$ based on a specific condition to generate $Y_i$). Now, the thing to notice is that the points of $Y_i$ would be separated non uniformly in "time". Should I be concerned about this before doing any analysis (such as computing autocorrelation) on $Y_i$? I feel that it should not matter because I could consider the subscript $i$ in $Y_i$ to just be an index to a specific event in time based on my filter. My intention is to find out if filtering out a time series of returns in a certain way can help me forecast future returns using the data of past (filtered) returns. That is I will be trying to model forecasts for $Y_i$ instead of modelling forecasts for $X_t$.

Comment: Hi: I don't think you should use a time series where observations were specifically removed from the series.

Comment: @markleeds Could you please explain why?

Comment: Hi: The whole idea behind the modelling of time series is that there are ( hopefully) existing autocorrelations at different integer lags. One uses those autocorrelations to build the model. So, if you take out observations at random points, the autocorrelation properties gets destroyed. So, It will be misleading to use autocorrelation to build the model if data points have been removed. Also, from a practical perspective, you will have larger spacings between some observations compared to others. It's not clear how you would deal with that ?

Comment: @markleeds Consider this case where I am trying to model returns of an asset when some news related to that asset is put out or let’s say that I am looking at tweets related to that asset. My idea was to filter out those return values that came in just after a tweet or news related to that asset.Based on this I get a new series which though separated non uniformly in “actual time” but still can be assigned a new index with uniform separation. Isn’t it still possible to observe autocorrelation at a fixed lag (where the lag is not in the “actual time” but in the new index that I have assigned)?

Comment: Hi: So, you are trying to A)  ELIMINATE the cases where there is a news item-tweet or B) model those cases ?

Comment: Hi: I read it again and it seems that you want to focus on the news related-tweet returns of that asset. But the first thing you need to do is decide on a return horizon. Are you considering returns 30 minutes from the when the tweet occurred etc. Secondly, ask yourself what you really want to know because it doesn't seem like you'd need to make a modified time series if you ask the right questions ? What exactly are you trying to do with the returns right after the tweet-news item ?  Do you want to test some kind of hypothesis ?

Comment: It's often the case that the question(s) you are asking can be answered without necessarily constructing some new time series that's adjusted so that those news-related returns are gone ? I think that's what you're planning on doing and it's probably not necessary and won't lead to anything useful.

Comment: @markleeds It's true that it may not be useful to do this. I am mainly concerned about mathematical correctness. Is it right to take out points and construct a new time series from those points and do analysis on them. Can it give me spurious results? The news/tweets thing was just an example and I agree that there are better ways in which that can be done.

Comment: Hi: I'm not saying there are better ways nor criticizing. I'm saying that there must be a question or an issue that you want to investigate and that that question-issue can possibly be answered without maintaining the time-series framework.